# Apache Beam execution

Tags: java, maven, apache-beam

I'm following this [example](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-java/) but in the step: ***Run WordCount***, throught direct command

```
$ mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.apache.beam.examples.WordCount \
 -Dexec.args="--inputFile=pom.xml --output=counts" -Pdirect-runner
```

And finally I have this error:

```
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 12.065 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2018-10-02T17:36:05+02:00

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.6.0:java (default-cli) on project word-count-beam: An exception occured while executing the Java class. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot define class using reflection: Could not find sun.misc.Unsafe -> [Help 1]

[ERROR]

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.


[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [Java Development Kit (JDK) version 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html). Verify that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set and points to your JDK installation.

To understand this change better, read:

- The official Feature Request [JEP 260: Encapsulate Most Internal APIs](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/260).
- [Understanding sun.misc.Unsafe](http://mishadoff.com/blog/java-magic-part-4-sun-dot-misc-dot-unsafe/)